# R dataframe split by factor then apply and tidyr

Tags: r, dataframe, split, apply, tidyr

There is 8 week internet experiment. Data is gathered on each participant, who can start the experiment at any date. The idea is to calculate the exercises done by each participant in the first week, in the second week and so on. So the result should be a participant times 8 matrix/data frame.

- each participant can start at any date, but the experiment is closed after 8 weeks
- each partisipant can do as many exercises as he/she wants.

here an example

```html
df <- data.frame(
        fac=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d"), 
        date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-05","2017-01-13","2017-01-25","2017-02-10","2017-01-06","2017-01-16","2017-01-28","2017-02-02","2017-02-07","2017-01-11","2017-01-19","2017-01-24","2017-01-31","2017-02-09","2017-01-12","2017-01-24","2017-01-29","2017-02-04","2017-02-19","2017-03-08"), 
        sessions=c(1,2,3,6,5,1,3,2,3,3,1,5,3,2,4,1,3,5,2,6,6)
        )
```

My idea is to:

1. add an "0" column (df$count<-0)
2. split the data frame by factors [split(df, df$fac)] 3
3. take the date value-subtract the date value that is the first entry, add 1, divide by 7 and then round up. *[roundup((date2 -date$1$+1)/7)]*. This gives me exactly the number of week in which the participant did the exercises.
4. with tidyr: reorganize the whole data frame so that values in every week are summed together (participant times 8 data frame)

But I have no idea how to correctly implement the step 3 and to combine with step 4

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us why step 3 is failing.

Comment: well I dont know which of the apply functions to use in this case. and how corectly to fix the "first date" in apply function.  i could do this easily in excel, but still gapping the knowlwdge in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(fac) %>% 
    mutate(time = ceiling(1+difftime(as.Date(date), as.Date(date[1]), units = 'weeks')))
summarize(df, total_sessions = sum(sessions))
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I place ceiling() comand? And how could I add 1 to difftime(as.Date(date), as.Date(date[1]),? As otherwise, the first day is always =0 week ?

Comment: Made the changes. If these were really that hard, don't you think you should learn some R?

Comment: Thanks for your help, learning R is exactly what I'm doing right now (@coursera). Unfortunately I have to work with some data too big for excel right now and that pushes me to my boundaries. So I understand your impatience, but simple don't have other choice right now, as to learn by doing. However, thanks a lot!